# Embedding of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ into $\mathbb{C} $

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Why we always fix an embedding $\sigma$ of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ into $\mathbb{C} $? Simply we can take the set of algebraic numbers inside $\mathbb{C}$ and can consider the natural map. What is the advantage of taking a different embedding instead of the natural one?

Comment: What counts as "the natural one" depends on how you construct $\overline{Q}$.  In particular, if you build it as a direct limit of algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, then there is no obviously "natural" way to embed it in $\mathbb{C}$.  The issue is basically this: In $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ there is an element $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2=2$.  Should $\alpha$ be viewed as the same as $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: we can think $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C} $ and can take the inclusion map. @ChrisEagle

Comment: My point is that "think[ing] of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$" is really nothing other than picking an embedding of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ into $\mathbb{C}$, and there is more than one way of doing this.